# Listing all Azure Runbooks in Automation accounts across multiple subscriptions

Tags: powershell, azure, automation, azure-resource-manager

I have been searching high and low and I can't even find a simple method to just list runbooks using powershell... 
I have 4 subscriptions and several automation accounts in each subscriptions, it can be tedious when I'm trying to find a particular runbook, browsing through the console.
So if anyone knows a simple way to list automation accounts and then their runbooks, so I could potentially create a simple loop to cycle through my subscriptions this would be extremely beneficial.

Thanks.
Josh

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work for you.  You would obviously have to add authentication and a subscription switcher for Azure RM.

```
foreach ($account in Get-AzureRMAutomationAccount){
Get-AzureRmAutomationRunbook -ResourceGroupName $account.ResourceGroupName -AutomationAccountName $account.AutomationAccountName
}
```